# Detecting timestamp and feature where anomaly occurs with autoencoder

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection

Is it possible according to you to use the latent space of a deep autoencoder to detect the index of the sample and the column/s (features) where an anomaly occurs or am I losing information with compression? I have a multivariate time series dataset